# Get the id of the list a sortable item came from?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, overall I have a word bank, and I'm trying to allow the user to drag any of the words into several other boxes, except I'm not allowing duplicates in any of the boxes, including if a word is dragged back to the word bank. A. And I'm trying to edit the text to make it smaller once it's dragged into the other boxes, or larger again if it's dragged back into the word box.

Not all of that is working yet.

So I'm starting out:

1) I need to accurately get the id's and classes of all the elements and lists. Right now: If I drag one list item to a different list, how can I access the `id` of the previous list it came from? My `ui.sender[0].id` is outputting the `id` of my word item, not the `id` of the previous list it belonged to.

2) Additionally, if there are several items in a list, how can I access those ids? I used `var element = $(this).sortable("toArray")` and it's not accessing them correctly; it comes up as undefined when I have multiple items in each list, and I test via `element[0].id`, etc.

Here's a portion of what I have in JS:

```js
var origin = null;
$("#wordBank,.words").draggable({
  helper: "clone",
  connectToSortable: ".sort",
  start: function() {
    origin = $(this).parent()[0].id;
    }
});

$(".words,.sort").sortable({
  connectWith: "#wordBank,.sort",
  receive: function(event, ui) {
  
  
    ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
    var currentListID = this.id; //where the item is dropped
    var originatedID = origin; //where item came from
    
    var itemContent = ui.item[0].innerHTML; //content in item
 
    var currentListLength = this.children.length;

  //alert("Ok");
  //alert("currentListID = " + currentListID);
  //alert("item content = " + itemContent);
  //alert("current list length = " + currentListLength);

  //Here I thought I could access all of the elements in a list if 
  //they had at least two items, but it's not working
  var element = $(this).sortable("toArray");
  alert("element[0] = " + element[0].id);

  
    
    
  }
  });
  $().disableSelection();
```

```css
.border {
  border: 2px solid green;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul id="wordBank" class="bank1">
  <li id="word1" class="words">Word1</li>
  <li id="word2" class="words">Word2</li>
  <li id="word3" class="words">Word3</li>
  <li id="word4" class="words">Word4</li>
  <li id="word5" class="words">Word5</li>
</ul>

<div id="drop1" class="border sort">1. </div>
<div id="drop2" class="border sort">2. </div>
<div id="drop3" class="border sort">3. </div>
<div id="drop4" class="border sort">4. </div>
```

Comment: If you click the `<>` you can provide a [mcve]

Comment: I created a snippet for you. Run it and fix the errors. such as this trailing bracket: `ui.item[0].id)` <<<

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Let me know if you have any advice on fixing how I use toArray!

Comment: @mplungjan the answer there is that their list elements have no id's. Mine do, so I dont think that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are many things that need to be fixed before you can try to run your code:

- `($this)` needs to be changed to `$(this)`, in jQuery all objects are called with `$(selector)`.
- Instead of using `alert()` use `console.log()` for logging or try to debug the code with your browser.
- `obj` is not defined in the code, try to check it was correctly defined before using it.

And to get the source element `id` of the dragged element, you can use `start` event of **[jQuery-ui `draggable`](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/)** to track the dragged element's parent `id` when the drag opertaion is started.

This is the right code:

```
var origin = null;
$("#wordBank,.words").draggable({
  helper: "clone",
  connectToSortable: ".sort",
  start: function() {
    origin = $(this).parent()[0].id;
  }
});
```

**Demo:**

This is an updated and revised version of your code with the right code to track this `id`:

```js
var origin = null;
$("#wordBank,.words").draggable({
  helper: "clone",
  connectToSortable: ".sort",
  start: function() {
    origin = $(this).parent()[0].id;
  }
});
$(".words,.sort").sortable({
  connectWith: "#wordBank,.sort",
  receive: function(event, ui) {

    ui.item.toggleClass("highlight");
    var currentListID = this.id;
    var originatedID = origin;
    var itemContent = ui.item[0].innerHTML;
    var currentListLength = this.children.length;

    console.log("Ok");
    console.log("currentListID = " + currentListID);
    console.log("originatedID = " + originatedID);
    console.log("item content = " + itemContent);
    console.log("current list length = " + currentListLength);

    var element = $(this).sortable("toArray");
    console.log("element[0] = " + element[0]);


    if (currentListID === "#wordBank") {

      console.log("removing list-inline-item on " + itemContent);
      ui.item[0].classList.remove("list-inline-item");
    } else if (!ui.item[0].classList.contains("list-inline-item")) {
      ui.item[0].classList.add("list-inline-item");
    }
    if (originatedID === "wordBank") {

      ui.item.css("font-size", "10px");
    } else if (currentListID === "wordBank") {
      ui.item.css("font-size", "20px");
      if (ui.item[0].classList.remove("list-inline-item"));
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul id="wordBank" class="bank1">
  <li id="word1" class="words">Word1</li>
  <li id="word2" class="words">Word2</li>
  <li id="word3" class="words">Word3</li>
  <li id="word4" class="words">Word4</li>
  <li id="word5" class="words">Word5</li>
</ul>

<div id="drop1" class="border sort">1. </div>
<div id="drop2" class="border sort">2. </div>
<div id="drop3" class="border sort">3. </div>
<div id="drop4" class="border sort">4. </div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! I will add those now and test. Also, it was a mistake that I wrote ($this), so I given the code I am still unable to access elements in a list after I complete toArray....do you have suggestions for that?

Comment: @sGlow well it's another problem, there.

Comment: Hi, okay so there's a problem I'm only just now realizing. Draggable's start is only fired when I first drag it, but not after multiple drags. Is there a way to access the parent after the first time I drag it??? Even when I use drag: the same issue occurs